# Calculate a $\infty^0$ limit using `de l'hopital` rule.

Tags: calculus

I have to calculate the following limit:

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} 2x^{1/\ln x}$$

So I tried to start:

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} 2x^{1/ \ln x} = \infty^0 $$
From here on I noticed that I have to use `de l'hopital` rule. but don't really know how and I need help.

If the math representation doesn't clear, so the exerice is:

`2x^(1/ln x)` as x $\to \infty$

thanks in advance.

Comment: Try calculating the limit of the logarithm of your expression.

Comment: Are you sure you've read the question correctly?  $x^{\frac 1{\ln x}} = e$ so the limit is trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is almost trivial and doesn't require l'Hospital:

$$2x^{\frac1{\log x}}=2e^{\frac1{\log x}\log x}$$

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log x}{\log x}=1$$

and thus

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}2x^{\frac1{\log x}}=2e$$

Perhaps your function is mistyped?